# Self-Referential Table Fields In MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table which has a "foreign key" referencing itself.  This would be very useful, except I am uncertain how to add the first record to such a table.  No matter what I add, I cannot provide a valid "foreign" key to the table itself, having no entries yet.  Maybe I'm not going about this correctly, but I want this table to represent something that is always a member of itself.  Is there a way to "bootstrap" such a table, or another way to go about self-reference?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One option is to make your field `NULL`-able, and set the root record's parent key to `NULL`:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_1 (
   id       int   NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
   value    int   NOT NULL,
   parent   int   NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES tb_1(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.43 sec)

-- This fails:
INSERT INTO tb_1 VALUES (1, 1, 0);
ERROR 1452 (23000): A foreign key constraint fails.

-- This succeeds:
INSERT INTO tb_1 VALUES (1, 1, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)
```

Otherwise you could still use a `NOT NULL` parent key and point it to the root record itself:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_2 (
   id       int   NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
   value    int   NOT NULL,
   parent   int   NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES tb_2(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.43 sec)

-- This fails:
INSERT INTO tb_2 VALUES (1, 1, 0);
ERROR 1452 (23000): A foreign key constraint fails.

-- This succeeds:
INSERT INTO tb_2 VALUES (1, 1, 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)
```

Comment: If I were to use the second approach, (tb_2), how could I know for sure what number to use for the third parameter?

Comment: @Joshua: The third parameter is the same as the first parameter (for the root record). That is, the `parent_id` of the root record is the same as its `id`. Then for other rows, simply reference the appropriate `parent_id` normally.

Comment: @DanielVassallo What about temporarily disabling the "NOT NULL" just to insert the first record? Is it possible? This would be great to ease recursive queries without worring about infinite loops.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Then perform the insert and then, set it back to 1 after. It is a session variable though so a disconnect will reset it, and it will not affect other connections.

Comment: Yes, you can do this in phpMyAdmin.