# Dataset and self referencing relationships Insert Exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dataset, foreign-keys

I am using c# datasets with a MSSQL back end. I have a table that references itself. When I add a parent row then add a child to  that, without calling update in between I am getting a constraint exception. I think it is because the inserts are not being performed in the same order the entities were added. Is there any ways around this? I want the user to be able to add items and then commit to the database at the end (when they have confirmed it is all correct).

Here is my table definition and a sample application:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AssetServiceItems] (
    [ServiceItemID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Parent] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AssetServiceItems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ServiceItemID] ASC) WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF,
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AssetServiceItems]
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [AssetServiceItems_parent] FOREIGN KEY ([Parent]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AssetServiceItems]([ServiceItemID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AssetServiceItems] CHECK CONSTRAINT [AssetServiceItems_parent]
```

and the program...

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

  RelTestTableAdapters.AssetServiceItemsTableAdapter adapter = new RelTestTableAdapters.AssetServiceItemsTableAdapter();
  RelTest dataSet = new RelTest();

  var parent =  dataSet.AssetServiceItems.NewAssetServiceItemsRow();
  parent.Description = "Parent";
  dataSet.AssetServiceItems.AddAssetServiceItemsRow(parent);

  var child = dataSet.AssetServiceItems.NewAssetServiceItemsRow();
  child.Description = "child";
  child.SetParentRow(parent);
  dataSet.AssetServiceItems.AddAssetServiceItemsRow(child);

  adapter.Update(dataSet);

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE
>   constraint "AssetServiceItems_parent". The conflict occurred in
>   database "RelTest", table "dbo.AssetServiceItems", column
>   'ServiceItemID'.

Comment: `The only limitation to self-referential relationships is that entity instances cannot be related to themselves in a parental relationship. This creates a circular reference.` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb955303.aspx)

Comment: Parent entry should go with null value for parent column and child entries can be added after once some parent exists. I might be not very clear, Although this question is about mssql but [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971593/self-referential-table-fields-in-mysql/2971596#2971596) should help you.