# How would I define a foreign key that points to the same table

Tags: relational-database

This might simply be poor design.  My goal is to have a table that contains a foreign key point to the same table.  The example I've though of is if you're storing books, and you want to keep track of the sequel in a particular series.  your table might look like this:

Books

```
|id|         title|sequel|
|--|--------------|------|
| 1|Harry Potter 1|     3|
| 2|Great Gatsby  |  null|
| 3|Harry Potter 2|  null|
|------------------------|
```

I would want the sequel column to be bound to an id in this same table.  preferably, you would restrict it to a DIFFERENT id in the same table.  can I simply define this column as a foreign key pointing back to the Books table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-Referential Table Fields In MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971593/self-referential-table-fields-in-mysql)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971593/self-referential-table-fields-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely can:

```
-- Add the foreign key
ALTER TABLE books ADD CONSTRAINT books_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (sequel) REFERENCES books (id);

-- Make sure it's different than the id
ALTER TABLE books ADD CONSTRAINT book_id_sequel_chk
CHECK (id <> sequel);
```